# Code defined in func not working but runs in main setupui func (pyqt5)

Tags: python

I am making a YouTube downloader for which I created a function which will run when user press download button but this works when the code is in the `setupUi` function (main function created by pyqt5). The problem is that it does not work when defined inside another function. I do not know why this is happening. The following is the code which I want to run.

```
def group(self):
    if i == 0:
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.scroll)
        self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 20, 431, 91))
        self.groupBox.setTitle("")
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 10, 371, 21))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label.setText("b")
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.groupBox)
        self.progressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 50, 221, 20))
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 24)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")
```

The following the code of main `setupUi` function

```
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(662, 423)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.b1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.b1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 20, 81, 31))

        self.b1.clicked.connect(self.func)
        self.b1.setPalette(palette)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.b1.setFont(font)
        self.b1.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);")
        self.b1.setObjectName("b1")
        self.subwin = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.subwin.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 70, 531, 251))
        self.subwin.setStyleSheet("background-image:")
        self.subwin.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.subwin.setObjectName("subwin")
        self.scroll = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scroll.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 529, 249))
        self.scroll.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        self.subwin.setWidget(self.scroll)
        self.input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.input.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 20, 351, 31))
        self.input.setObjectName("input")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
```

I hope this code will be enough and relevant.